# Howto created trimmed directory tree while using wget for ftp download

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, wget

Am using wget for download files from ftp.

Ftp folder have name  /var/www/html/

Inside this folder is located tree of folders & files, ~20 levels.

Am trying make ftp download (have no ssh access), of this all with wget.

```
wget -- recursive -nv --user user --password pass ftp://site.tld/var/www/folder/
```

This one command runs Ok. But it creates an folder structure.

```
~/back/site.tld/var/www/html/my-files-and-folders-here
```

Question:
Is any possibility - to say wget, not create ~/site.tld/var/www/html/ but make all tree, in current folder?
i.e. ~/back/my-files-want-here/ I.e. - to trim/cut certain path?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for `--no-host-directories` and `--cut-dirs` in the manpage.

This should work like expected (maybe you have to increase/decrease *cut-dirs*):

```
wget --recursive --no-verbose --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=3 --user user --password password ftp://site.tld/var/folder
```

Comment: There really should be a way to auto-detect the cut depth and it should be default. A user would expect that he/she just gets `d/` and its content when he uses `wget -nH fpt.site.com/a/b/c/d/`. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a auto-detect workaround. You could try `wget -nd fpt.site.com/a/b/c/d/ -P "d"`.